# Strange line width in memoir

Tags: memoir, line, page

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside, openany]{memoir}
\AtBeginDocument{
\settrims{0pt}{0pt}
\settypeblocksize{257mm}{165mm}{*}
\setlrmargins{30mm}{*}{*}
\setulmargins{20mm}{*}{*}
\setheaderspaces{*}{*}{1}
\checkandfixthelayout
}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{equation}
x = x
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I wish for the text to occupy all the width of the typeblock. However, the amount of characters in line seems fixed, and the only way I can occupy more width is to enlarge the font. Strangely, all of the other things (including the numbers in the `equation` environment) also seem to obey that invisible right margin at which the text ends.
Strangely enough, the pagenumber is typeset at the correct place!

I have read all of the chapter II of the `memoir` manual, however after experimenting with the length of the margins, I have come to the conclusion that the margins may not be the case here. I have failed to find any examples of this in the documentation of `memoir`. I am quite certain that I have overlooked something, but I have found nothing in reading the manual further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wrong part is `\AtBeginDocument`. The parameters and `\checkandfixthelayout` should be in the preamble.

I added `showframe` just to show the elements of the page.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside, openany]{memoir}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\settrims{0pt}{0pt}
\settypeblocksize{257mm}{165mm}{*}
\setlrmargins{30mm}{*}{*}
\setulmargins{20mm}{*}{*}
\setheaderspaces{*}{*}{1}
\checkandfixthelayout

\begin{document}

\blindtext
\begin{equation}
x = x
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can also just use the showlocs pagestyle

Comment: @daleif Didn't know about that.

Comment: Many thanks! This seems to fix it for me.